# Kotlin parallel flow

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

How set flow to run operation asynchronously like parallel() in java?

```
IntStream.range(0, size)
                .boxed()
                .parallel()
                .map(this::doSomethingLong)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

I wanna do some long operation in flow asynchronously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you can do something like this:

```
// Perform everything on a background thread using flowOn operator
fun simple(size: Int): Flow<Int> = flow {
    for (i in 0..size) {
        emit(i)
    }
}.transform { it ->
    emit(doSomethingLong(it))
}.flowOn(Dispatchers.Default)

fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        simple().collect { it ->
            println(it) // Collect on main thread
        } 
    }
}
```

Note that collecting happens in the context of the calling coroutine. Therefore if you want to collect on a different thread, you can specify it, for example, like this

```
withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
    simple().collect { ... }
}
```